# System of differential equations 9

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Let 
\begin{align*}
(x')^2+(y')^2&=1\\
2x'y'y&=((x')^2-(y')^2)x
\end{align*}
Can anyone give a explicit solution (or prove that exist) , a graphic or an aproximate solution?
Thank you!

Comment: The second equation rearranges to $$ 2\frac yx = \frac{x'}{y'} - \frac{y'}{x'} $$ which tells you that the _direction_ of the curve depends only on the direction to the origin. This suggests that it may be useful to switch to a conformally equivalent coordinate system $(x,y) = (e^w\cos z, e^w\sin z)$, where the direction is now a function of $z$ only, so there's some hope of writing $w$ as a function of $z$, involving an integral.

Comment: One explicit solution is $(x,y)=(0,t)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $z=x+iy$, then your equations are 
$$
|z'|=1\text{  and }Re(z'^2z)=0
$$ 
or $z'^2z=ia$ with $a$ a real function. Taking absolute values in that results in $|z|=|a|$ or $a=\pm|z|$. This in turn allows to compute $z'$ as the complex square root of 
$$
w=\pm i\frac{\bar z}{|z|}=\exp(i(-\arg(z)+(k+\tfrac12)\pi))
$$ 
The square root of the complex unit $w$ (if $w\ne-1$) is 
$$
z'=\pm\frac{1+w}{|1+w|}=σ_2\frac{|z|+σ_1i\bar z}{\Bigl||z|+σ_1i\bar z\Bigr|}
$$
or using the angles of the unit vectors
$$
z'=\exp\left(i\left(-\frac12\arg(z)+\frac\pi4+k\frac\pi2\right)\right)
$$ 
which should give $4$ different systems of differential equations to follow for the 4 choices of $σ_1,σ_2\in\{\pm1\}$ resp. $k=0,1,2,3$, all unit directions in perpendicular pairs of opposite directions.

---

The solution curves to $z'\sqrt{z}=\pm\frac23(1\pm i)$ have the same direction fields but different time parametrizations. But for this equation, integration is easily possible and leads to $$z^{\frac32}=\pm(1\pm i)t+C$$ or
$$
z(t)=z_0\left(1\pm z_0^{-\frac32}(1\pm i)\,t\right)^{\frac23}
$$
where the main branch is chosen for the rational power.

---

A way to write the last approach without rational powers is to lift the direction field to the double cover $w^2=iz^3$ which implies $4w'^2=9iz'^2z$. As this is real by the second equation, the direction field is equal to $w'=\pm 1$ or $w'=\pm i$, i.e., the solution curves are the families of lines parallel to the coordinate axes. Including a re-parametrization in $w(u(t))^2=iz(t)^3$ and inserting into the first equation gives 
$$
|u'(t)|^2=|w'(u(t))|^2|u'(t)|^2=\frac94|z|=\frac94|w(u(t))|^{2/3}.
$$